# DearPyGUI путь к файлам с кирилицей

Tags: python, dearpygui

Есть необходимость отображать картинку в интерфейсе.
Проблема возникает если в пути к картинке используется кириллица, тогда load_image() выплёвывает None.

```
    def add_image(self, path, width: int = 200, height: int = 100):
        img = load_image(os.path.abspath(path))
        if img is None:
            print(path, 'Не загруженно')
            return
        tag = os.path.split(path)[1]
        with texture_registry(show=True):
            add_static_texture(tag='texture_{tag}', width=img[0], height=img[1], default_value=img[3])
        add_image(texture_tag=f"texture_{tag}", parent="image_board", width=width, height=height)
```